# How to show value while sliding the range slider in ionic framework?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want my code to show the range value (on the slider itself) while I am sliding the slider in my ionic app.

My slider code is:

```
    <h5>Scale</h5>
    <div class="item range">
        <i>1</i>
        <input type="range" id="inputRange" name="volume" min="1" max="10">
        <i>10</i>
    </div>
```

What changes are required in my code?

Comment: Try: "pin" attribute:  
If true, a pin with integer value is shown when the knob is pressed. Defaults to false. See: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/range/Range/#input-properties

Answer (score 4):

In ionic 3, I have achieved it like this.

```
<ion-badge>{{knobValues}}</ion-badge>
<ion-range min="1" max="100" step="1" [(ngModel)]="knobValues"></ion-range>
```

Comment: add knobValues in .ts file too

Answer (score 3):

You can add a ng-model to the input for example `ng-model="sliderrange"` and display this in your html anywhere with `{{sliderrange}}` like this:

```
<h5>Scale</h5>
<div class="item range">
  <i>1</i>
  <input type="range" id="inputRange" ng-model="sliderrange" name="volume" min="1" max="10">
  <i>10</i>    
</div>

{{sliderrange}}
```

I would also recommend setting the value in your controller with `$scope.sliderrange = 5;` for example so the value will be shown on the scope init. Otherwise the value will show up after the user uses the slider for the first time.